# how to remove isolated special characters using regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

How do I change isolated hyphens to `0` without altering signed numbers or words with hyphens?

```
dt <- c("-","-123","33","-","-12.45", "total-revenue")
```

I have tried using:

```
gsub("(\\-(?<=[^a-z0-9]))","0",dt,perl = TRUE)
```

which changes it to:

```
[1] "0"             "0123"          "33"            "0"             "012.45"        "total0revenue"
```

Ideally my output should be:

```
[1] "0"             "-123"          "33"            "0"             "-12.45"        "total-revenue"
```

Comment: Try `sub("^-$","0", dt)` The `^` and `$` make sure you match the entire string. Or you could do `replace(dt, dt=="-", "0")`

Comment: @MrFlick Just what I was looking for, thank you! You should post as an answer, so I can accept it.